# Clearing MacOS terminal in .Net Core C#

Tags: c#, macos, terminal

I'm currently developing a console app and I've designed my menus in a way such that the active element of the menu is highlighted with a specific background color. To re-render the menu after the change of an active element I'm moving the cursor with the `Console.SetCursorPosition(0,0)` to the very top of the window to then rewrite all the lines. Also, the `Console.Clear()` method is used to clear the console before moving to another menu (which can be of different size).

However, this approach does not seem to work on MacOS - the `Console.Clear()` method is not working, and the `Console.SetCursorPosition(0,0)` is not working in the way it should - the menus overlap each other instead of being cleared.

Is there any way to make this work on MacOS, or is it impossible due to some of the features of the MacOS terminal?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use the [CursesSharp library](https://github.com/sushihangover/CursesSharp) to do this.

CursesSharp provides C# bindings to the `ncurses.h` library for Unix-like systems.  In theory, you ought to be able to do anything you want to do that the ncurses library is capable of, including clearing the screen and setting the cursor position.